# Django 1.5 - url template tag and reverse function not generating correct url based on current_app instance

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm attempting to create a blog app that is used multiple times by multiple apps. However, neither the url templatetag nor a call to reverse within the view generate the correct url based on the current_app namespace instance.

I am using Django 1.5.1

myproject/urls.py (note that test1, test2, and test3 are different apps)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test1/', include('test1.urls', namespace='test1', app_name='section')),
    url(r'^test2/', include('test2.urls', namespace='test2', app_name='section')),
    url(r'^test3/', include('test3.urls', namespace='test3', app_name='section')),
)
```

test1/urls.py (and the same for test2 and test3)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('test1',
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
    url(r'^articles/', include('blog.urls', namespace='articles', app_name='blog')),
)
```

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog',
    ...
    url(r'^new/$', blog_new, name='new'),
    url(r'^new/preview$', blog_preview, name='new_preview'),
    ...
)
```

blog/views.py

```
def blog_new(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    r = resolve(request.path)
    context = {
        ...
        'current_namespace': r.namespace,
        'preview_url': reverse('section:blog:new_preview',
            current_app=r.namespace)
        ...
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context, current_app=r.namespace)
```

Also, in _sidebar_menu.html

```
<a href="{% url 'section:blog:new_preview' %}">
```

When I navigate to any of the following:

> /test1/blog/new
>
> /test1/articles/new
>
> /test2/blog/new
>
> /test2/articles/new
>
> /test3/blog/new
>
> /test3/articles/new

I always get the same result for "preview_url" context variable and for the href in the anchor tag - "test1/blog/new/preview". Yet, the context variable "current_namespace" contains the accurate value that is expected.

I'm pulling my hair out here! How do I achieve the modularity that I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a successful work around for anyone interested.

For the blog_new view function that I listed in the opening question, the desired preview_url can be acquired by doing the following:

```
def blog_new(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    r = resolve(request.path)
    context = {
        ...
        'current_namespace': r.namespace,
        'preview_url': reverse(r.namespace + ':new_preview')
        ...
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context, current_app=r.namespace)
```

Notice the change in the call to reverse(). This time I constructed the viewname parameter to use the current namespace rather than a default one.

The same goes for using the url template tag. In the following I use the "with" tag to construct the viewname based on the current_namespace context variable that I passed to the template.

```
<a href="{% url current_namespace|add:':new_preview' %}">Preview</a>
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to do nested apps in this way. And if there's a better way I'd love to learn of it